# JQuery array for use in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays

I'm not overly confident in my own abilities but here goes. I want JQuery to find the data attribute of all elements with a particular class. Then I want it to add them to the ajax dataString array.

There are 6 elements with that class all of which have the data attribute. Rather then include them all by id attributes surely their is an easier way. Would this work.

Here goes

```
var data[] = $('.sidescroller').attr('data');

var dataString = 'function=' + scripts + '&data[]=' + data[];

//execute PHP
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataString,
         url: '<?php echo $thisposturl;?>?scripts',
```

Any ideas how to do it.

Marvellous

Comment: What are trying to achieve here? do you want to set the data attribute values of all element with class `sidescroller`? If so how do you want the data, should they be coma separated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, No, `.attr()` will only get the attributes of the *first* element in the list

```
var data = $('.sidescroller').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('data');
}).get();
```

Secondly, don't construct query parameters by hand, it's error prone and can also be abused:

Send the data parameter as a set of key-value pairs thus:

```
data: {
    'function': scripts,
    'data': data
}
```

Comment: +1 Good solution! However, I do wish to point out the incorrect usage of the `data` attribute. Please see my revised answer for further info on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think the .attr() function works on the first element among the matched elements a better way would be to use the map function.

```
var dataArr = [];
$(".sidescroller").map(function(){
    dataArr.push($(this).attr("data"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [HTML5 specs.](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#custom-data-attribute) custom `data` attributes should be named like this: `data-name`. Then you can use [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to fetch the data. Example below:

**HTML**

```
<div id="foo" class="has-data" data-test="foo"></div>
<div id="bar" class="has-data" data-test="bar"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var data = {};
$(".has-data").each(function(){
    data[this.id] = $(this).data("test");
});

$.post('/', data);
```

Comment: two problems - 1. `.map()` returns a jQuery object, not an array - 2. `data` should be a key/value pair object.

Comment: @Alnitak, oh yes you are right about this, thanks for pointing it out. Thought about it the  wrong way, so I will revise my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataString = 'function=' + scripts;

$('.sidescroller').each(function() {
    dataString += '&data=' + $(this).attr('data');
}       

//execute PHP
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 data: dataString,
 url: '<?php echo $thisposturl;?>?scripts',
```

Would this work?

Comment: @Alnitak's is probably the better option.

Comment: and if 'data' should happen to contain characters that should have been escaped?

Comment: @Alnitak are you looking for some sort of prize? I already acknowledged that yours was the better option.

Comment: Nah, I've reached my rep cap already - I was just pointing out exactly why you shouldn't build query strings by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
var data= [];
$('.sidescroller[data]').each(function(){
    data.push($(this).attr('data'))
});
var strdata = data.join(",");
alert(strdata );
```

You can find a working sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HLGFN/).